# Using awk to print first and last fields

Tags: awk

My awk script to print the first and last fields of each line does not work as I expected. It prints the last field only for the last line. How do I fix this?

```
c:\awk>type file_lists.t01

dgo_files.txt date_frame_full.f90 xdtff_good.f90   
dtd_files.txt date_frame_full.f90 xread_date_time_frame_stream_dir.f90  
xem_files.txt kind.f90 foo.f90

c:\awk>gawk '{ print $1 " " $NF }' file_lists.t01

dgo_files.txt 
dtd_files.txt 
xem_files.txt foo.f90
```

Comment: Please add your desired output (no description, no images, no links) for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file seems to use [carriage returns](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/carriage-return/info). I suggest with GNU awk:

```
gawk 'BEGIN{ RS="\n|\r\n" }{ print $1 " " $NF }' file_lists.t01
```

See: [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, **RS**, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)